# MeanJS addSubMenuItem not working

Tags: javascript, meanjs

Using MeanJS 4.x, and I'm trying to add another menu item to the Admin menu (the same menu that has the Manage Users menu item by default).

Following the `users-admin.client.menus.js` code as an example, I created my own `thing-admin.client.menus.js` as such:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('things.admin')
    .run(menuConfig);

  menuConfig.$inject = ['menuService'];

  function menuConfig(menuService) {
    menuService.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'admin', {
      title: 'Manage Things',
      state: 'things.list'
    });
  }
}());
```

It does nothing.  While the code runs (I can console.log inside the menuConfig function and get the expected log), the subMenuItem is not added.

I can put the exact same code inside the `users-admin.client.menus.js` and it works.  I can work that that for now, but it seems like it's not following the conventions of the Mean.js template so I'd rather have it in my module rather than theirs.

I can also change `addSubMenuItem` to `addMenuItem` in the `thing-admin.client.menus.js` and it works (just not how I want; it adds it as a peer of the admin menu, rather than as a child).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I had to pass the core.admin as a dependency to app.registerModule - because the admin menu had to exists before I try to add a sub-menu to it.

```
  app.registerModule('things.admin', ['core', 'core.admin']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try running a console.log on your menuService to see if it was actually added?

Make sure that your menu is called 'admin' and not 'things-admin'

Comment: This space is for answers, not comments. Once you have sufficient reputation on the site, you'll be able to leave comments on questions, and answers.